# How do I convert this function into a loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have an array of letters of an unknown number of elements which contains lower case letters. I have written a function for converting a lower case number to its ASCII value

```
int returnVal (char x)
{
    return (int) x;
}
```

I am trying to combine all of these values into one number. Subtracting 87 from each of these means that the value is always a 2 digit number. I am able to combine an array made up if two elements by:

```
returnVal (foo[0]) - 87) + returnVal (foo[1] - 87) * 100
```

an array made up of three elements by

```
returnVal (foo[0]) - 87) + returnVal (foo[1] -87) * 100 + returnVal (foo[2] - 87) * 100 * 100
```

I am multiplying each element by 100^its position in the array and summing them. This means that [a,b,c] would become 121110 (yes, the 'flip' having the value for 'c' first and 'a' last is intentional). Could anybody programme this (for an array of an unknown number of elements)?

EDIT: I have received no form of schooling at programming/computer science at any pojnt in my life, this is not homework. I am trying to teach myself and I have got stuck; I don't know anybody in person who I could go to for help so I asked here, apologies to those of you who are offended.

EDIT2: I know that this opinion is going to annoy a lot of people; what is the purpose of stackoverflow.com if it is not to exchange information? If I were a child who was stuck with my homework (I'm not) surely that is a valid reason for using stack overflow? Many people on this website seem to have the mindset that if a problem is asked by a beginner then it is not worth answering, which is completely fine because your time is your own. However, what genuinely bugs me is the people who see a question which they deem trivial and say "homework" and vote it down immediately. I think that this website would be far better if there wasn't an "minimum-level" knowledge required in order to ask questions, the "elitist" mindset is just childish in my opinion.

Comment: Two nits to pick. First, why have a function that simply performs a cast? Why not inline the cast? Second, what is a "lower case number?" It might also help if you gave some more sample inputs and outputs, and a more clear description of the problem. It appears you are performing ASCII manipulation: are you trying to sum up offsets from the start of the alphabet? Is the result supposed to be a decimal number?

Comment: An array with unknown number of elements in most cases leads to disaster. Also SO is not for making your homework. Provide some code on your own and then we can provide some help.

Comment: What is a "lowercase number"?  And the function you have written will not convert a character to an integer - it will just cast the character to an integer.

Comment: I am self taught and this is not homework, it was a typo, apologies. I meat lower case LETTER.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think the part that annoyed the lone downvoter is "Could anybody program this for an array of an unknown number of elements?" rather than "Could anybody **help me** program this for an array of an unknown number of elements?" Lots of participants here routinely help beginners, as long as the question is phrased as asking for help in performing your task by yourself. Good luck with the site, and try to follow the explanation in my answer below.

Comment: What is the significance of 87 (0x57)?

Comment: It assigns a = 10, b = 11 etc so that all of the numbers are 2 digits long and 100 can be used as the base every time

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks a lot, I'll definitely try to word things more carefully in future

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a learning exercise, here are some hints for you to complete the task yourself:

- Prepare a value that will server as the "running total" for your number so far.
- Start the running total at zero.
- When you convert a number, say, `"1234"`, to an `int`, this value would first become `1`, then `12`, then `123`, and finally `1234`
- The final value of the running total is your end result
- To go from a previous value to the next, multiply the prior value by ten, and add the value of the current digit to it
- Your `returnVal` does not make sense, because in C you can very often avoid an explicit conversion of `char` to `int`. You can definitely avoid it in this case.
- Making a function `int digit(char c)` that returns a value of decimal digit, i.e. `c-'a'`, would be a lot more useful, because it would let you get rid of your `c-87` in multiple spots.

Answer (score 0):

```
char array[SIZE];
long factor=1;
long result=0;
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    result+=returnVal(foo[i])-87)*factor;
    factor*=100;
}
```

This should work for as long as `long` is large enough to hold the value of `100^the position` and, of course, as long as the result does not overflow.

Comment: Thank you, but it says that "[SIZE] is not declared in this scope"

Comment: SIZE is the length of the array, presumably defined earlier or known by any other means. If you were to use a `std::vector`, you would initialize it somehow with your array (eg. by adding your array elements via `vector::push_back(x)` and use `for (unsigned i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)` to define the loop.